# nginx returns 500 for error as string, Instead of 500 as integer,

Tags: nginx

I have a rails app, that responds to mobile devises for api calls. In somecases, it is returning a "500", So we are getting a typecasting error as it is expecting integer. We don't want to handle integer and string statuses seperately.

So is there a way to return "500" as integer in nginx.

Comment: How is the 500 returned?

Comment: I guess something is breaking in the railsapp. we are stil evaluating it. The idea is to handle it properly if some other corner cases comes and breaks the app. So we want to give the mobile user proper message.